# Null space of a matrix mcq

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $M$ be the set of all $m\times n$ matrices with real entries. Which of the following statement is correct?

1. There exists $A$ of order $2\times 5$ belonging to $M$ such that the dimension of the null space of $A$ is 2\,
2. There exists $A$of order $2\times 5$ belonging to $M$ such that the dimension of the null space of $A$ is 0\,
3. There exists $A$of order $2\times 5$ belonging to $M$ and $B$ of order $5\times 2$ belonging to $M$ such that $AB$ is the identity matrix\,
4. There exists $A$ of order $2\times 5$ 
   belonging to $M$ whose null space is $\{(x,y,z,w,l)\in \mathbb{R}^5 :x=y,z=w=l\}$

If I take $A$ that is a matrix whose first row is $(1,0,0,0,0)$ and second row is $(0,0,0,0,1)$ then all the options  3 becomes correct but I am not sure about the others
 .

Comment: only one option is correct

Comment: What do you know about the values of $m$ and $n$?  If they are not specified then all four statements are correct.

Comment: sorry A is of order 2*5

Comment: Is the $m$ in 4. the same as the $m$ in the first line? If not, please edit the question appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints**.

- rank$(A)={}$ number of independent rows of $A\le{}$ total number of rows of $A$.
- nullity$(A)={}$ number of columns of $A$ minus rank$(A)$.
- $\{(x,y,z,w,m)\in \mathbb{R}^5 :x=y,z=w=m\}=\{(x,x,z,z,z): x,z\in \mathbb{R}\}$, and the dimension of this is. . . ?